# How can I include a column from a join table in a rails association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, join

I am joining two Models with a join table so that I can put a status on the relation:

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products_tests
  has_many :products, through: :products_tests

  def products_with_status
    products_tests = ProductsTest.includes(:product).where(test_id: id)
    products_tests.map do |products_test|
      products_test.product.as_json.merge(status: products_test.status)
    end
  end

end

class Products < Application Record
  has_many :products_tests
  has_many :tests, through: :products_tests
end

class ProductsTest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :test
end
```

There is a `status` column on `ProductTest` that let's me toggle a a product from "active" to "paused" for each test.

I'd like to merge in the `status` column when I use the `products` association from `Test`. I've hacked together `products_with_status` above but was wondering if there is a more "Rails" way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: are you going to save it after the merge? Also why do you want to merge it because you will always have the status column existing in the join table? Lastly, within the Test class, can't you access `products_tests` simply without using that active_record query?

Comment: I'm denormalizing the data to send it over the wire. It's stored in Redux in the client so it is "persisted" there. TBH, I prefer to keep Redux _exactly_ the same as postgres but this is a quick and dirty solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new `has_many` association

```
has_many :products_with_status, -> { joins(:products_tests).select("DISTINCT products.*, products_tests.status") }, through: :products_tests, class_name: "Product", source: :product
```

Then you can do

```
Test.find(1).products_with_status.first.status
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns the wrong number of records.

Comment: add `DISTINCT` in select statment. I have updated the code

Comment: I think the issue is that the `joins(:products_tests)` is superfluous because the association also has `through: :products_tests`. Without the `joins` I think I'm getting the right results. Thanks!